# Why can't I save a number with decimal values in my input box? It only allows integers to be updated?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an text input box on my form, and when the form initially displays it displays the price with a decimal point like `910.01`.

```
const initialState: OrderWindowState = {        
    price1: 910.01,
    price2: 911.33,
    
  }


const [state, setState] = useState<OrderWindowState>(initialState);



<input type="text" name="price1" value={state.price1} onChange={price1OnChange} />


const price1OnChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("price1OnChange called:" + event.target.value);    
    setState({
      ...state,
      price1: +event.target.value
    })
  };
```

When I begin to update the number, if I enter a decimal point `.` I can see it in my `console.log` message, but the number stored in my state and visibly in my text input it only displays integer values (with no decimal values).

Why is it doing this?

Comment: ...why are you using `<input type="text">` instead of `type="number"`?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `+event.target.value`, the string value is converted into a number - and numbers don't have trailing `.`s. So, when the component re-renders, the previously typed `.` won't be reflected in state, so it won't be seen in the controlled component's value either.

One approach would be to keep the *string* input in state, and to only convert it to a number later when needed. For example:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [price1, setPrice1] = React.useState(910.01);
    const price1OnChange = (event) => {
        setPrice1(event.target.value);
    };
    const price1Number = Number(price1);
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="price1" value={price1} onChange={price1OnChange} />
        <div>
          Number value:
          {Number.isNaN(price1Number) ? 'Not a number - correct your input' : price1Number}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

The above is in JS just so that the snippet can be run easily, but the same approach works for TypeScript - change your `OrderWindowState` to accept strings instead of numbers, and change `price1: +event.target.value` to `price1: event.target.value`.

Because the values for price1 and price2 are separate, you might consider using separate states for them (like I did above and as React recommends).